# How to merge data frames with different types using R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, inner-join

I’m trying to use functions from the “dplyr” library to join two large data frames, but one column (say X) has characters in one data frame and integers in the other. This is the error I get:
Error in `inner_join()`:
! Can't join on `x$MAK_MOD` x
`y$MAK_MOD` because of incompatible
types.
ℹ `x$MAK_MOD` is of type >.
ℹ `y$MAK_MOD` is of type >.
B

Any way I can solve this without physically manipulating the data?

Comment: Use `as.character()` on the integer variable before the join.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.